# Detect paraboloid shaped sections of an array

Tags: python, numpy, pattern-matching

I am trying to detect *paraboloid-shaped* points within a [`numpy.ndarray`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html).

I have a dataset, smoothed it using a Wiener filter (using the package NIFTy4): it is saved as `.csv` and can be found [here on Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kRcX8sJcNgAxapffYCbgEroNG2_2YcTN) or [here on PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/8KhmCjYm).

[image: Sample]

What I am looking for is a way to identify the sections within my array that describe **upwards opened paraboloids**.

In the provided sample I'd like to detect 5 such shapes. The focus is mainly on the width (beginning and end) of the shape rather than the actual minimal position.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you already have a generator for such curves? If so, could you add it to the question? It could come in handy to those that attempt to answer.

Comment: I don't have a generator. I extract them from a measurement and smooth them over. But since the original data is in a rather chaotic shape aand is just a noisy version of this I have just attached the final datavector. (thanks for the help with formalities it helps a lot :) )

Comment: Is finding local minima of such smoothed graph sufficient for you?

Comment: @Phteven Calculate the slope of the line at each point. The points your looking for are where the slope goes from negative to positive. That's going to happen often but you could compare the area of each instance. Or look for fluctuations in the area under the curve.

Comment: @zch : That is a point that I am currently working on but it is not quite sufficient. more important than the "mean position" is the width of the parabola

Comment: I believe I have succeeded doing what you asked for: [here](https://imgur.com/a/R9DFnxe). I'm in the process of writing the answer.

Comment: These are parabolas, not paraboloids.

Comment: How do you define the endpoints of the shapes ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Solution using `numpy`

For this solution I am going to use `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np
```

### Datasets

#### Creating a dataset

OP [Phteven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10077730/phteven) was kind enough to provide the dataset to work with, but since link to datasets tend to die off I have created also a function to generate *similar* curves.

```
def polyval_points(n):
    """Return random points generated from polyval."""
    x = np.linspace(-20, 20, num=n)
    coef = np.random.normal(-3, 3, size=(5))
    y = np.polyval(coef, x) * np.sin(x)
    return x, y
```

#### Loading the dataset

```
def dataset_points():
    """Return points loaded from dataset."""
    y = np.loadtxt("data.csv", delimiter=',')
    x = np.linspace(0, 1, num=len(y))
    return x, y
```

### Elaborating the points

#### Slope convolution

Since the points are discrete we have to *mean* the slopes. One such approach is via an uniform kernel.

```
def convolute_slopes(y, k=3):
    """Return slopes convoluted with an uniform kernel of size k."""
    d2y = np.gradient(np.gradient(y))
    return np.convolve(d2y, np.ones(k)/k, mode="same")
```

#### Obtaining the paraboloids

Now that we can compute the convoluted slope, determine where it switches direction and choose those intervals that have mean slope greater than the absolute mean times a coefficient that describes how 'slopy' the paraboloids have to be.

```
def get_paraboloids(x, y, c=0.2):
    """Return list of points (x,y) that are part of paraboloids in given set.
        x: np.ndarray of floats
        y: np.ndarray of floats
        c: slopyness coefficient
    """
    slopes = convolute_slopes(y)
    mean = np.mean(np.abs(slopes))
    w = np.where(np.diff(slopes > 0) > 0)[0] + 1
    w = np.insert(w, [0, len(w)], [0, len(x)])
    return [(x[lower:upper], y[lower:upper])
            for lower, upper in zip(w[:-1], w[1:])
            if np.mean(slopes[lower:upper]) > mean * c]
```

### How to use this and visualization

First we load the dataset and generate a couple more:

```
datasets = [dataset_points(), polyval_points(10000), polyval_points(10000)]
```

Then, iterating on every dataset:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(10 * len(datasets), 10))
for i, points in enumerate(datasets):
    x, y = points
    plt.subplot(1, len(datasets), i + 1)
    plt.plot(x, y, linewidth=1)
    for gx, gy in get_paraboloids(x, y):
        plt.plot(gx, gy, linewidth=3)
plt.show()
```

#### The results

[image: Paraboloids]

Comment: just: WOW. I joined yesterday and gave it a 20% or so chance and 12 hours later I have something to work with. THANK YOU. I'll try and tweak it a little more and get back to you

Comment: Update: you can improve the result even further using the maxima of the second derivative

Comment: With smoothing convolution or the original data?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, the curves are smooth and noise-free so that the parabola vertices just correspond to local minima.

You don't specify how the beginning and endings are defined, so I will assume "up to the inflection points". To locate these, you can compute the first order differences to estimate the slope, and detect the first maximum of the absolute slope on both sides.

Don't expect good accuracy on these limits, this is an ill-posed problem.

Comment: the position is found by a local minimum

Comment: the width is not by the inflection points but by finding the point where it "drops off". the reason why I cannot find a better mathematical formulation is because it is a measured quantity and not a known functional relation

Comment: @Phteven: what do you call "drops off" ? It is important to use meaningful and unambiguous descriptions otherwise we waste time making irrelevant suggestions.